# Foundation + Gulp and jQuery error

Tags: jquery, gulp, zurb-foundation

I install foundation-sites via NPM and I try to run this in my gulpfile.

```
domain: 'localhost',
  webpack: {
    plugins: [
      new NgAnnotatePlugin({add: true}),

    ],
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html'}
      ]
    },
    sassLoader: {
      includePaths: [
        require('foundation-sites').includePaths,
        require('bourbon').includePaths,
        require('node-neat').includePaths[1]
      ]
    }
  },
  webpackDevServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
```

After run I can see jQuery error:

```
jQuery is not defined
```

After add jquery in gulp file:

```
var jQuery = require('jquery');
```

and modify this section:

```
webpack: {
    plugins: [
      new jQuery
      new NgAnnotatePlugin({add: true})
    ],
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html'}
      ]
    },
    sassLoader: {
      includePaths: [
        require('foundation-sites').includePaths,
        require('bourbon').includePaths,
        require('node-neat').includePaths[1]
      ]
    }
  },
  webpackDevServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
```

I can see error:

```
/Users/kajus/HTDocs/DEV-INDUSTRY/dev-industry-frontend/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:28
                                if ( !w.document ) {
                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined
    at new module.exports (/Users/kajus/HTDocs/DEV-INDUSTRY/dev-industry-frontend/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:28:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/kajus/HTDocs/DEV-INDUSTRY/dev-industry-frontend/Gulpfile.js:13:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Liftoff.handleArguments (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:116:3)
    at Liftoff.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:193:16)
```

And i don't have conception to fix it.